# Changing pointplot legend in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to change the label for the legend and items in the legend for this plot. Right now the label for the legend is "Heart" and the items are 0 and 1. I would like to be able to change all of these to something else, but am unsure how. Here is what I have so far.

```
sns.set_context("talk",font_scale=3)
ax =sns.pointplot(x="Heart", y="FirstPersonPronouns", hue="Speech", data=df)
ax.set(xlabel='Condition', ylabel='First Person Pronouns')
ax.set(xticklabels=["Control", "Heart"])
```

Any help would be appreciated! Also, I'm assuming this is a set parameter that I don't know about, is there a comprehensive list of these? I can't seem to find one in the documentation.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to use the labels you want in the dataframe itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to changing the column names of the data frame, is to create a new legend using the same legend handles (this is what determines the colored markers), but with new text labels:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.pointplot(x='sex', y='total_bill', hue='time', data=tips)
leg_handles = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()[0]
ax.legend(leg_handles, ['Blue', 'Orange'], title='New legend')
```

[image]